# How do i add an if-else statement in these lines of code?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, if-statement, android-sqlite

I want to make sure my user fill in all the spaces provided in the interface before they are qualified to create an account. Where can I add the if-else statement in these lines of codes? I am doing this to ensure the user inserted all the data before going to the profile page. Please help me guys.

```
 createacc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, profile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            getData();
        }
    });
}

private void getData() {
    email = "" + Pemail.getText().toString().trim();
    name = "" + Pname.getText().toString().trim();
    age = "" + PAge.getText().toString().trim();
    phone = "" + Pphone.getText().toString().trim();
    preferenceselected = "" + Ppreferenceselected.getText().toString().trim();
    password = "" + Ppassword.getText().toString().trim();

    String timeStamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    boolean id = dbHelper.insertInfo(
            "" + imageUri,
            "" + email,
            "" + name,
            "" + age,
           "" + phone,
            "" + preferenceselected,
            "" + password,
            ""+timeStamp,
            ""+timeStamp

    );

        Toast.makeText(this, "Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: It seems clear in these lines of codes. You have to check the value of each 'get' method to be sure that they are not null or empty. If they have correct values assign values to the variables, otherwise  throw an exception or show a toast to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after you trim all the values contained in the `EditText`s, check if any of them is empty:

```
email = Pemail.getText().toString().trim();
name = Pname.getText().toString().trim();
age = PAge.getText().toString().trim();
phone = Pphone.getText().toString().trim();
preferenceselected = Ppreferenceselected.getText().toString().trim();
password = Ppassword.getText().toString().trim();
if (email.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || age.isEmpty() || phone.isEmpty() || preferenceselected.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all the info...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return; 
}
String timeStamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();
......................................................
```

The expression:

```
email.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || age.isEmpty() || phone.isEmpty() || preferenceselected.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()
```

will return `true` if one of the operands returns `true` and will not check the rest because of [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and in such a case a `Toast` will be displayed and the code will return without proceeding with the creation of the account, so no need for `else...`.

Also there is no need for all these `"" + ...` concatenations because the result of `toString().trim()` is a `String`.

Comment: what if I wanted to check if the user already exist or not? for instance, existing user cannot use the same email to register account again? How can I do that? your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Just like you created the method `insertInfo()` create another inside your SQLiteOpenHelper class one say `userExists()` with 1 argument the name of the user and in this method by using `rawQuery()` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) check if the name exists and if it does return true. All you need then is another if after the existing if: `if (dbHelper.userExists(name)) {....}`

Answer (score 1):

Make getData function to return a boolean value which provides the validation that all data is entered by the user or not. Then in onClick function call getData function to check data validation which returns true if data entered correctly else false. According to the return value, you can handle your requirement.

Here is the solution:

```
createacc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(getData()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, profile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
         }else{
             Toast.makeText(this, "Please Fill All The Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
         }
     }
 });


private boolean getData() {
   email = "" + Pemail.getText().toString().trim();
   name = "" + Pname.getText().toString().trim();
   age = "" + PAge.getText().toString().trim();
   phone = "" + Pphone.getText().toString().trim();
   preferenceselected = "" + Ppreferenceselected.getText().toString().trim();
   password = "" + Ppassword.getText().toString().trim();
   String timeStamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();

   if(!email.isEmpty() && !name.isEmpty() && !age.isEmpty() && !phone.isEmpty() && !preferenceselected.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
       boolean id = dbHelper.insertInfo(
            "" + imageUri,
            "" + email,
            "" + name,
            "" + age,
            "" + phone,
            "" + preferenceselected,
            "" + password,
            ""+timeStamp,
            ""+timeStamp
       );
       return true;
    }else return false;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `getData` to return a `boolean` and change your `onClick` method to something like `if(getData()) startActivity(intent);`. Then put your checks for completeness within your `getData` method, to return `true` only if all data is validated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways can do this. You can do something like this

```
private void getData() {
    email = "" + Pemail.getText().toString().trim();
    name = "" + Pname.getText().toString().trim();
    age = "" + PAge.getText().toString().trim();
    phone = "" + Pphone.getText().toString().trim();
    preferenceselected = "" + Ppreferenceselected.getText().toString().trim();
    password = "" + Ppassword.getText().toString().trim();

   if(!email.equals("") && !name.equals("") && !age.equals("") && !phone.equals("") && !preferenceselected.equals("") && !password.equals(""))
 {
    String timeStamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    boolean id = dbHelper.insertInfo(
            "" + imageUri,
            "" + email,
            "" + name,
            "" + age,
           "" + phone,
            "" + preferenceselected,
            "" + password,
            ""+timeStamp,
            ""+timeStamp

    );

        Toast.makeText(this, "Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }else {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Please Fill All The Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

> Note: It only checks for empty values. If you want to add some other
>   logic like password is less then 6 chars that's not included here